# ant build generating same class files while packaging the war file

Tags: ant

Below is the Ant script i am trying in GAE project but when i look into the war file i see two class for each java file.

Just a fyi, WAR file created i open in winrar but even when i extract it winrar keeps on asking me to either replace existing file message. Not sure how even same file name & extension is present in one folder. Also i checked the "dist" & "classes" folder i does not have duplicate file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<project name="AntExample1" default="war">

    <path id="compile.classpath">
        <fileset dir="war/WEB-INF/lib">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
        <mkdir dir="dist" />
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="init" >
        <javac destdir="build/classes" debug="true" srcdir="src">
            <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="war" depends="compile">
        <war destfile="dist/AntExample.war" webxml="war/WEB-INF/web.xml">
            <fileset dir="war"/>
            <lib dir="war/WEB-INF/lib"/>
            <classes dir="build/classes"/>
        </war>
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="dist" />
        <delete dir="build" />
    </target>

</project>
```

Comment: Is this exactly the same `build.xml` file used for your project? Have you ever checked whether there're classe files under `war/WEB-INF/classes` copied before `war` tag?

Comment: I ran into a similar problem.   Fixed it by excluding the classes folder in the fileset.
Added this line:
 

    <exclude name="WEB-INF/classes/**" />